Handling Three Sets of Nested Quotation Marks with Csquotes
Consider, for example, the quote

found here.
I would like to replicate sentences such as the above using Latex; however, the following code does not work:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

The Lord said, \enquote{Go to my people and tell them, \enquote{The Lord says, \enquote{You are a fallen people\ldots}}}
\end{document}

QUESTION: How may I modify the above code in order to properly handle these three sets of nested quotes?
Thank you.

csquotes supports this out-of-the-box. Just pass it the maxlevel=<n> option when loading the package, where <n> is the required number of levels. For example,
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}


Thank you. That seems to work.

@DDS I'd actually forgotten you had to do anything to make this work, so was rather puzzled at first.
